# Two basic questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, divisibility, absolute-value

Here are two basic questions to which I currently do not know the answer:

> **(1)** If $a > 0$ and $b$ are integers (where $b$ is negative), then if there exists a (necessarily) negative integer $c$ such that $b = ac$, then is it true that $a \leq |b|$?

> **(2)** Does the inequality $|c - d| \leq |c| + |d|$ hold **for all integers** $c$ and $d$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

- Trying special cases for **(1)**: Let $b = -36$, $a = 4$, and $c = -9$.  Then $b=ac$, and the inequality $a \leq |b|$ holds.  (How about if $c = -1$?  Then we have $b = -a$, and it is then true that $a \leq |b| = |-a| = a$.)  However, I currently have trouble articulating a proof for **(1)**.
- Trying special cases for **(2)**: Let $c = -d$.  Suppose that $c > 0$.  Then $$2c = |2c| = |c - d| \leq |c| + |d| = |c| + |-c| = c + c = 2c,$$
  which does hold.  (Again, I currently have trouble articulating a proof for **(2)**, as I have doubts if it is valid for all integers $c$ and $d$.)

Comment: Concerning $(1)$ : We have $|b|=|ac|=|a|\cdot |c|\ge |a|\cdot 1=|a|$

Comment: Concerning $(2)$ : Apply the triangular inequality for the numbers $c$ and $-d$ and use $|-d|=|d|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) follows since $|b|=a|c|\geq a$ (since $|c|\geq 1$)

(2) is true by the triangle inequality (holds for real numbers $c,d$ more generally)